# How can I prevent pseudo-users from being created for anonymous Hudson / Jenkins job builds?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

With the Hudson or Jenkins continuous integration servers, when a build is triggered either by an anonymous user, or by the CI server polling the repository, a pseudo-user is created with the data scraped from the commit information of the last commit.

How do I prevent this, as it's cluttering the list of registered users? I try to default to using post-receive hooks for scheduling builds, but for some repositories (e.g. those hosted by SourceForge), this is not an option as the machine running the repository is prevented from accessing external URLs

Comment: what do you mean cluttering? Whats the exact problem your trying to solve?

Comment: well, I don't want a pseudo-user to be created everytime a Jenkins finds that a SourceForge-hosted Hg repository contains some new revisions. By cluttering, I mean that when selecting the "People" view, it lists not only actual Jenkins users, but also the last committer on a project when Jenkins polls and finds new changes / the last committer when a build is requested by an anonymous user.

Comment: Does my response answer your question? Please either pick an answer or give us more information to help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent these from being created, as they are involved with how Jenkins logging and tracking works. However, if you need to see a list of only "real" users, you can do this easily by going to manage jenkins/manage users - users that lack a login will not appear.

Comment: Aha. Is there any way of white-listing the email addresses that get build status notification via email?

Comment: Yep. In the settings for the job, you can manually specify the recipients and uncheck "Send separate e-mails to individuals who broke the build" to prevent other people from being emailed. If you want even more control, there is a plugin that gives you granular control over emails - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin